# Random Dice roll using arrays and a counter (Always prints 0, even if a condition is true)

Tags: java, arrays

I've set a counter in my second function type method so that every time, the roll adds to '2' of 1000 rolls, it will print the number of times in the main method. Except the value is always returned as 0, when the program runs, ignore the empty if/else blocks, I have not filled those yet As I am trying to fix something first that will help me with the rest of them.

I have tried researching other ways to accomplish this, except the binary Search seemed most reasonable except in this case, Either I am using it incorrectly, or another problem is occurring in the program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class de
{
  public static void main (String args []) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    int[] counts = new int[1000];
    int [] counts2 = new int[1000];

    int userInput;
    String input;
    int counter = 0;


    System.out.println("Hello and welcome to the program");
    System.out.println("In this program two six sided dices will be rolled and one eleven sided dice will be rolled (1000 times each)");

    System.out.println("The dices will be rolled to determine the odds of how many times the roll 2 comes up on both dices and die");
    System.out.println("(Press any key to be prompted) with user Instructions");
    input = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("To determine the amount of times snake eyes is rolled with two six sided dices press '1'");
    System.out.println("For the amount of times two is rolled on a eleven sided die press '2'");
    System.out.println("For both press '3', or to exit this program press '4' ");
    userInput = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();

    if (userInput == 1)
    {

      System.out.println("is " + counter);
    }

    else if (userInput == 2)
    {
      // enter code...(Not finished)
    }

    else if (userInput == 3)
    {
      // enter code...(Not finished)
    }

    else 
    {
      // enter code... (Not finished)
    }
  }
  // pass array into method
  void myMethod (int[] counts, int[] counts2)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)
    {

      counts [i] = (int)(Math.random ()*6+1)+ (int)(Math.random ()*6+1);
      counts2 [i] = (int)(Math.random ()*10+2);
    }
  } // pass array into method
  public static int Secendmethod (int [] counts, int counter)
  {
    Arrays.binarySearch(counts, 2);
    for(int i = 0; i <counts.length; i++) 

      if (counts[i] == 2) {
      counter++;

    }
    return counter ;
  }  
}
```

Comment: You don't call the calcuating methods

Comment: How do you propose I do that?

Comment: myMethod is never called, and Secendmethod (note the typo and non-camelcased) isn't called either

Comment: How would I call them?

Comment: Would, de anything = new de(Secendmethod) , work, to be placed in the main?

Comment: You know that `Arrays.binarySearch(counts, 2);` effectively does nothing, right?

Comment: I can see that now, seeing that my if statement is doing the same thing there.

Comment: Maybe the problem is my print statement, I'm not sure if it's acceptable to just print 'counter'. Also how would I call those two methods?

Comment: I'm afraid you need to get a Java book and start with even simpler tasks.  You seem to be missing the most basic stuff.

Comment: Sidenote: The word "dice" is already plural (the singular is "die") so it's wrong to pluralize it again to say "dices".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would go about comparing for a roll of 2

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class de
{
  public static void main (String[] args ) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    int[] counts = new int[1000];
    int[] counts2 = new int[1000];

    int userInput;
    String input;
    int counter = 0;

    userInput = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();

    if (userInput == 1){ //used in your previous code
        rollDice(counts,6); //populates array count with Random int by 6
        rollDice(counts2,6); //populates array count with Random int by 6
        counter = compareDoubles(counts,counts2,1);
        System.out.println("is " + counter);
    }

  }
  /*
   * count: Array to store resulting dice rolls
   * diceSize: number of different results from rolling dice
   */
  static void rollDice(int[] counts, int diceSize){
        for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++){
            counts [i] = (int)(Math.random ()*diceSize+1); 
        }
  }
  /*
   * firstCounts: first set of numbers
   * secondCounts: second set of numbers
   * num: number to compare both sets against
   * returns number of times both sets evaluate to num
   */
  public static int compareDoubles (int [] firstCounts, int[] secondCounts, int num)  {
    int amount = 0;

    if(firstCounts.length <= secondCounts.length){ //make sure we don't get arrayOutOfBounds
    for(int i = 0; i <firstCounts.length; i++) 
        if (firstCounts[i] == num && secondCounts[i] == num) 
            amount++;
    }
    return amount;
  }  
}
```

*EDIT

If the arrays are not being used later, (only being used to count dice rolls, it's not very efficient). I extended roll dice to return the amount of times a number was rolled by all the die.

To do what we did above in a more efficient and dynamic way call

```
counter = rollDice(1000, 2, 6, 1);
```

which would go to

```
     /*
           * rolls: number of times a dice is thrown
           * dice amount: number of di being thrown
           * diceSize: number of different results from rolling dice
           * number: number of times all dice land on number
           */
          static int rollDice(int rolls, int diceAmount, int diceSize, int number){
                int amount = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < rolls; i++){
                    int[] dice = new int[diceAmount];
                    boolean alltrue = true;
                    for (int j = 0; j < diceAmount; j++){ //Roll all the dice to a random number by diceSize
                        dice[j] = (int)(Math.random ()*diceSize+1); 
                    }

                    for (int j = 0; j < diceAmount; j++){ //Recount all the dice rolled to see if they all landed the same way
                        if(dice[j] != number)
                             alltrue=false;
                }
                if(alltrue) //All dice were the number
                    amount++;

            }
            return amount;
      }
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I need to keep a certain format, I need one method to generate random numbers, while the other counts the amount of times the dies add to two.

Comment: Can you somehow place the counting of the two's into their own method?

Comment: They are, the compareDoubles method takes the two arrays or dice rolls and a number (to see it they're the same) then counts them and returns amount. If this is different from what you're looking for please explain

Comment: I want the methods to be generic, only do one specific function, and thus be interchangeable, for instance If I wanted to change the amount of dies, it should be relatively quick

Comment: Also, if you don't mind could you explain what is happening at the Lines:   if (userInput == 1)
    {
        rollDice(counts,6);
        rollDice(counts2,6);
        counter = compareDoubles(counts,counts2,1);

Comment: Another thing, I only want to use counts, not counts 2, counts 2 was going to be used for another function, to roll a completely differen't die

Comment: Do you need to store the dice rolls for any reason? Or are you only looking for the count of a certain roll?

Comment: Well for my assignment, I need to roll two six sided dies using 1000 arrays, and roll one eleven sided die (Count the number of twos) using 1000 arrays, thus totaling only two array methods, with the program you printed (Which works) it would total to 4000 arrays which would seem like inefficient programming.

Comment: I don't see why using an Array is necessary since you aren't using those number later (I added a method to my answer that removes the need for arrays, and allows it to be generic)

Answer (score 0):

Okay. First change your myMethod() to...

```
public static int[] create(int n)
{
    int[] temp = new int[1000];
    if(n == 6)
    {            
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = (int)(Math.random ()*6+1);
        }
    }
    if(n == 11)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = (int)(Math.random ()*10+2);
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Also change Secondmethod to...

```
public static int Secendmethod(int[] ar)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) 
    {
        if (ar[i] == 2) 
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter ;
}
```

Then change your if statement to:

```
if (userInput == 1)
{
  counts = create(6);
  System.out.println("is " + Secondmethod(counts));

}
```

For the userInput being two, make the first line: counts2 = create(11); and the second: System.out.println("is " + Secondmethod(counts2));

Good luck and feel free to ask questions!